# LinkItem: how to create a disabled / null link

Tags: 8, entities, uri

How do I create a LinkItem that will render into

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Do nothing</a>
```

or another form of unclickable link?

**Motivation:**

I am implementing a computed field of type link, which under some circumstances should become disabled. The HTML attribute `disabled` is not sufficient.

**Code:**

```
if ($disabled) {
  $url = 'internal:#'; # want: 'javascript:void(0)';
  $attributes = ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'disabled' => ''];
  $title = t('Disabled');
}

$field_item_list->createItem(0, array(
  'uri' => $url,
  'title' => $title,
  'options' => ['attributes' => $attributes],
));
```

Comment: What do you want to happen with javascript:void(0)? I'm not familiar with it. This thread suggests avoiding it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525002/6031948

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just want a NULL-link: ie render the text, but don't let the user click on it. I believe, `javascript:void(0)` is a perfectly acceptable technique for that. The drawback of `href="#"` is that it actually causes the page to reload when clicked.

Comment: Hmm, and you don't want to use a button or span? For accessibility and semantic HTML reasons, I would lean toward avoiding a link tag if it's not really a link.

Comment: I would gladly use a button or span, but this logic is inside a link field (aka LinkItem) of a custom entity type. LinkItem, of course, can only render an `<a>` element. – I guess this question is more or less philosophical: is LinkItem able to handle a null-like value for its url? No, it isn't. Should it be like this? I don't know. The `javascript:void(0);` is common in many sites and could be used here to represent a null value. Having said that, I agree with what you say about accessibility and semantics.

Answer (score 1):

A different option:

- Add a class to your disabled links.
- Create a JS behavior that targets a.your-class and uses preventDefault() on the click event.
- Add to libraries file for your module and add library as needed.

```
...
  $('a.your-class').click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
...
```